# How to Edit Google Chrome DevTools "Coverage" Option?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, inspect

I am trying to delete unused CSS and Javascript codes with the Google Chrome DevTools Coverage tab. But I can't edit or delete anything from the coverage tab. Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/tofbbw . Have any option for edit or delete codes from DevTools ? Does anybody know about it ? Please help me....

Comment: If you need to copy the covered and uncovered code just import JSON file and import in nachovz tools at https://nachovz.github.io/devtools-coverage-css-generator/. You can see both as seperated windows